# Issue with Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

This is a basic issue, but I'm hoping that someone will be able to walk me through this.

I'm dealing with fragments in Android and am simply trying to assign an inherited class (extends Fragment) to an object that is a Fragment.

```
public void changeFragment(View view){
    Fragment fragment;

    if(view == findViewById(R.id.fragment1)){
        fragment = new Fragment1(); 

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

My Fragment1 class looks like:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
}

}
```

The error is saying incompatible types. But if Fragment1 is extending Fragment, and I'm trying to assign Fragment1 to a Fragment, shouldn't it allow this?

Comment: Yes, if class `Fragment1` extends `Fragment` then you can assign an instance of the former class to a variable with the latter type.  Among the possible explanations, two seem particularly likely: (1) the version of class `Fragment1` that the compiler sees *does not* extend `Fragment` (maybe the class file is out of date with respect to the code), or (2) the error is not about that assignment at all.

Comment: Can you provide exact error you see? is it compiler error or runtime exception and how it looks like?